# Arduino の micros() , millis() のコード本体はどこにあるのでしょうか？

Tags: c++, c, arduino

こんにちは。

Arduino初心者です。

`Arduino.h` には `micros()` , `millis()` の定義は書かれているのですが
コード本体が記述されているファイルを見つけることができません。
どのファイルに記述されているかご存知の方、ご教授願えませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[環境]
Windows 10 pro 64bit
Arduino IDE 1.8.2
zipファイルを `c:\Arduino` に展開しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wiring.c` に実装があります。Github での当該ファイルへのリンクは[こちらです](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c)。

bakabon88 さんの環境においてどのパスにあるファイルか分かりませんが、同様のファイルがコンパイル時にリンクされていると思います。

私は Github 上のソースコードを検索して見つけました。

Comment: sayuriさん、nekketsuuuさん、ご回答ありがとうございました。ソースコードを見ることができました。
g++ のビルドの仕組み（コンパイル、リンクなどを経て実行コードができるまで）をよく理解していない初心者です。素朴な疑問ですが、PC内に実体ソースコードがなくてもビルドできるのでしょうか？

Comment: @bakabon88 別個の質問として新たに質問して頂けませんか？

Comment: すみませんでした。勘違いしてました。実体がありました。お騒がせしました。

Answer (score 1):

[Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L65-L104](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/2bfe164b9a5835e8cb6e194b928538a9093be333/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L65-L104)にあります。関数本体を引用する意義はないと考えますので、必要であればリンク先を参照してください。

Comment: sayuriさん、nekketsuuuさん、ご回答ありがとうございました。ソースコードを見ることができました。
g++ のビルドの仕組み（コンパイル、リンクなどを経て実行コードができるまで）をよく理解していない初心者です。素朴な疑問ですが、PC内に実体ソースコードがなくてもビルドできるのでしょうか？

Comment: すみませんでした。勘違いしてました。実体がありました。お騒がせしました。